# JavaScript with servlet Get method

Tags: javascript

I have the following form element in JSP:

```
<form name="testForm" action="./test.do" method="post">
</form>
```

Now I want to submit a form with a servlet get method using JavaScript.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would be unusual (and error-prone) to submit a forum using GET. Do you mean POST?

Comment: @Jim Blackler:I any other way to submit a Get request,Like iframe?

Comment: Sending a GET request could be done with an iframe, an image, a script, anything. My point is you're not supposed to submit data with GET (although you could send any data you liked with GET via URL parameters). If you have data to submit, use POST or PUT.

Comment: I'll note that there's nothing wrong with submitting a form using get. The concept being that GET should retrieve data and POST should be used whenever the call can modify data. If the form is just used as a way to gather parameters for retrieving data, then it's not unreasonable to use GET for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the method from post to get.

```
<form name="testForm" action="./test.do" method="get">
</form>
```

Now when it the form is submitted the data will be submitted using GET instead of POST params.